# How to add/update references without Visual Studio using a custom script?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build a previously created .NET application (VS2015 Community), but before building I have to solve several issues manually. One of these issues is to add/update reference to **System.Web.Mvc.dll** which is located in local project folder.

In Visual Studio 2015, this is fairly easy. Just click **References** and then proceed to **Add reference**, where you **Browse** the correct reference. However, I want to perform this step *without* using Visual Studio with my custom script, which performs this automatically.

Is this even possible to do without Visual Studio? If it is, what other requirements should be taken into account in general?

I am new with Visual Studio programming (mainly programmed with GNU/Linux), so I am not aware of all limitations or possibilities regarding to VS and Microsoft BuildTools.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The references are listed in the project file.

I've never been able to find proper documentation for those (but see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx, but when you inspect it it should become clear. You'll need to add to the ItemGroup which includes the references. It'll look something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System" />
  ...
</ItemGroup>
```

How you want to update the file is up to you, but an XSLT transformation seems a reasonable way, or your script could just do raw xpath stuff

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly I was looking for!